# Переменная в объединении не обновляет значение

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, double, объединение

Мне необходимо в своей программе осуществить побитовый вывод переменных short int и double, а также инвертирование задаваемого пользователем количества битов и старшего из инвертируемых. Для вещественной я использую объединение с дополнительной переменной unsigned long long (по размеру они получаются одинаковыми). Однако, почему-то у меня не получается обновить значение вещественной переменной (хотя в теории все должно работать) и если вводить позицию бита >= 32, то B.b1 ведет себя неопределенно.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//функция побитового умножения
void bin(long long k, int size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = size * 8; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (i%8==0)
            cout << "|";
        cout << ((k >> (i - 1)) & 1);
    }
    cout << "|\n";
}

long long invBits(long long k, unsigned short int pos, unsigned short int qntt)
{
    unsigned short int i;

    for (i = pos; i > pos-qntt; i--)
        k ^= (1 << (i - 1));

    return k;
}

int main()
{
    short int a, answer;
    unsigned short int n, q;
    union
    {
        double b0;
        unsigned long long b1;
    } B;

    printf("Enter short int: ");
    cin >> a;

    printf("Enter double: ");
    cin >> B.b0;

    //вывод размеров типов переменных (в байтах)
    cout << "Size of short int - " << sizeof(short int) << "\n";
    cout << "Size of double - " << sizeof(double) << "\n";

    //вывод представления переменных в бинарном коде
    cout << "Short int " << a << " in binary code:\n";
    bin(a, sizeof(a));

    cout << "Double " << B.b0 << " in binary code:\n";
    bin(B.b1, sizeof(B.b1));

    cout << "Which variable's bits would you like to change\n1 - Short int\n0 - Double\n";
    cin >> answer;

    cout << "Enter greatest bit to invert: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Enter quantity of bits to invert: ";
    cin >> q;

    if (answer)
    {
        a = invBits(a, n, q);
        cout << "Short int " << a << " in binary code:\n";
        bin(a, sizeof(a));
    }
    else
    {
        B.b1 = invBits(B.b1, n, q);
        cout << "Double " << B.b0 << " in binary code:\n";
        bin(B.b1, sizeof(B.b1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: В теории-то как раз не должно работать хотя бы потому, что type-punning через union - неопределенное поведение (в С++, но не в С).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, до этого у меня была версия с memcpy, что, видимо, не сильно лучше

Comment: c memcpy, кстати, (без использования union) изменение переменной заработало. Только вторая проблема с позицией бита >= 32 осталась

Comment: самое интересное то, что смещение на 31 бит (т.к. i - 1) дает число между 2^64 и 2^63, дальнейшие позиции начинаются с 0-й степени 2, причем это происходит через каждые 32 позиции. Переполнение?

Comment: надо было использовать массив битов, в задании это не запрещалось. Решение размещу позже

Comment: Нет, `memcpy` лучше. От него неопределенного поведения нет.

Comment: Сдвиг на ширину больше или равную ширине типа - тоже неопределенное поведение. Попробуйте заменить `k ^= (1 << (i - 1));` на `k ^= (1ull << (i - 1));`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно с уверенностью сказать, что этот ответ дан совместно с @HolyBlackCat, за что отдельное спасибо этому пользователю.

Первая проблема решается заменой объединения на две переменные и операцией memcpy:

```
printf("Enter double: ");
cin >> b0;
memcpy(&b1, &b0, sizeof(double));
```

Чтобы изменить значение double b0 после инверсии битов переменные нужно поменять в этой функции местами.

Вторая же проблема действительно устраняется с помощью приписывания к единице ULL (ull) - unsigned long long. Это позволяет инициализировать в 64-битной переменной биты, начинающиеся с 31-го (32, если нумеровать от 1 до 64).